# C++Builder XE3 64-bit application always requires rtl170.bpl

Tags: 64-bit, c++builder

I have built a 64-bit application with C++Builder XE3 that is running on a Windows Server 2003 (32-bit). I can compile it, but of course cannot run it in that computer.

I copied the .exe over to a Windows 7 (64-bit) computer and now it's complaining that rtl170.bpl cannot be found. I have explicitly set the project options to not use any Runtime Packages.

Is this a bug in XE3 or does it fail because I am building the application on a 32-bit computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to disable the "Use dynamic RTL" (linker).

Comment: In 64bit mode (on XE5 anyway, not sure about XE3) the "Use dynamic RTL" checkbox actually has no effect; the RTL linking is controlled by "rtl" appearing in the Runtime Packages list.

Comment: Yep, this was the setting in XE3. And whew, the exe size grew from 2MB to 12 MB! There's also another setting, "Link with the Delphi Runtime Library (rtl package and cp32mt.lib/cp32mti.lib)", but that I did not need to switch off

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the dependencies for a binary (exe, dll, etc.) that you have built.

This will show exactly where the dependency is coming from. One possibility is that your code depends on some other library or DLL, which in turn depends on `rtl170`.

Another thing to check is that you are actually looking at the right Project Options for what you are building. For example, say you are doing Win64-Release, then in Project Options, make sure the "Target" combobox says "Release configuration - 64-bit Windows platform" when you are on the "Runtime Packages" field.  (At that stage, "Link with runtime packages" should be unchecked).

Do a full rebuild of the project after confirming this setting, and of any dependent libraries you are linking.  (Example - if you also built OpenSSL and are linking to that, make sure that you had "Link with runtime packages" off for the build of OpenSSL).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to enable/disable the following settings under project options

- Packages

  - Runtime Packages

    - ❌  Link with runtime packages
- C++ Linker

  - ❌  Link with dynamic RTL
  - ❌  Link with Delphi runtime library
  - ✔️ Disable incremental link